# Remove all articles, connector words, etc., from a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a list that contains many sentences.  I want to iterate through the list, removing from all sentences words like "and", "the", "a", "are", etc.

I tried this:

```
def removearticles(text):


articles = {'a': '', 'an':'', 'and':'', 'the':''}
for i, j in articles.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
return text
```

As you can probably tell, however, this will remove "a" and "an" when it appears in the middle of the word.  I need to remove only the instances of the words when they are delimited by blank space, and not when they are within a word.   What is the most efficient way of going about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go for regex, something like:

```
def removearticles(text):
  re.sub('(\s+)(a|an|and|the)(\s+)', '\1\3', text)
```

or if you want to remove the leading whitespace as well:

```
def removearticles(text):
  re.sub('\s+(a|an|and|the)(\s+)', '\2', text)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I knew somebody was going to submit regex as the solution.  I'm afraid I'm an amateur, though.  Do you know of any good regex tutorials/references?

Comment: There's a tutorial [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html), I haven't done it all so I'm not sure how good it is though.  The main tool I use for designing regexs is [My Regex Tester](http://www.myregextester.com), makes it easy to see where and why things match.

Comment: Mastering Regular Expressions (by Friedl,O'reilly pub) is worth owning. http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/

Comment: doesnt work for me at all.                                                                          >>> text
'my friend is a guy'
>>> print re.sub('\s+(a|an|and|the)(\s+)', '\2', text)
my friend isguy
>>> print re.sub('\s+(a|an|and|the)(\s+)', '\1\3', text)
my friend isguy
>>> text = "a guy"
>>> print re.sub('\s+(a|an|and|the)(\s+)', '\1\3', text)
a guy
>>> print re.sub('\s+(a|an|and|the)(\s+)', '\2', text)  
a guy

Comment: Yeah, the second one doesn't work. Doesn't remove the spaces.

Answer (score 4):

This looks more like an NLP job than something you would do with straight regex.  I would check out NLTK (http://www.nltk.org/) IIRC it comes with a corpus full of filler words like the ones you're trying to get rid of.

Comment: It's called "stopwords" or "Stopwords Corpus" and can be retrieved directly [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/corpora/stopwords.zip). The full list of corpora is [here](https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/).

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of

```
articles = ['and', 'a']
newText = ''
for word in text.split(' '):
    if word not in articles:
        newText += word+' '
return newText[:-1]
```

Comment: Given that I'm unfamiliar with regex, I was thinking of solving the problem in the same way!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def removearticles(text):


articles = {'a': '', 'an':'', 'and':'', 'the':''}
rest = []
for word in text.split():
    if word not in articles:
        rest.append(word)
return ' '.join(rest)
```

`in` operator of dict run faster than list.

Comment: Does this run faster than regex?

Comment: @ParseItongue  I just test my method and regex solution provided by Senthil Kumaran. With Timer module, I process the NEWS.txt installed with Python2.6 which is 118kb. Both method run 1000 times, my method is a bit faster, around 2 seconds in my PC, than regex. Both method method is good enough, take anyone you like:)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [regex](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html). Iterator through your strings or (''.join the list and send it as a string) to the following regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> rx = re.compile(r'\ban\b|\bthe\b|\band\b|\ba\b')
>>> rx.sub(' ','a line with lots of an the and a baad')
'  line with lots of         baad'
```